# How can i get sound data using web service in ios?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

someone know idea regarding to fetching sound data from webservice? I used simple play, pause, stop sound to access application resources folder. Now i want to update this. plz, having some idea. thanks in advance.

Comment: Get audio url from the server and then convert as nsdata then you can play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for downloading audio file from server

```
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SoundURL"]];
```

after downloading

`AVAudioPlayer` has a method for playing sound from `NSData` object .
You can use

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)outError method of AVAudioPlayer
```